# lumen generate fake data with faker from given array

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, faker

I want to generate fake data for user with diffrent role ,

My file is below,

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class InsertUserSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {
        $faker = Faker::create();
        foreach (range(1, 10) as $index) {
            DB::table('user')->insert([
                'name' => $faker->name,
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'role' => 'admin',
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

From above code it will generate 10 records of admin role.

I want to generate records with different role from['admin','superadmin','client','agent','engineer']

how can I fetch value for role from given array of roles.

Comment: You can foreach with different users roles! Like 10 records of admin user role, 10 records of employee user roles!

Comment: thanks for help ,but it is final way , is there any other way from which I can generate above 10 records with different roles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method `randomElement($array)` of the faker to do the job like so:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class InsertUserSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run() {
        $faker = Faker::create();
        foreach (range(1, 10) as $index) {
            DB::table('user')->insert([
                'name' => $faker->name,
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'role' => $faker->randomElement([
                    'admin',
                    'superadmin',
                    'client',
                    'agent',
                    'engineer',
                ]),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

For reusability, I would suggest using model factories instead of creating the models directly in the seeder. You can read up on it [in the documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/testing#model-factories).

Comment: let me check above solution

Comment: it was not allowed me at that time ,told me that 2 mints remaining, now done :)